# How do I reference to layout objects (XML) using Java to develop apps?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

This is for example my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Wat wil je gemiddeld komen te staan?"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Typ het hier in"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Volgende"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText1" />
```

This is my Java code so far:

```
package com.firstapp.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }


}
```

Lets say I want EditText to have a maximum input of 2 decimals, how do I reference to  in Java to make these changes? So I basically want to add the logic to the XML layout objects but I don't know how to address them in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editText1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText1=findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Editable decimalNumber=editText1.getText();
   }
}
```

XML Layout changes for limiting input(maxLength)

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Typ het hier in"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, there won't be any main method in android

Please start writing your code in `onCreate` method after

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: @[person who disliked it], Could you please provide reason for it